# Stochastic uniform's step size in matlab's ga

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to understand the stoachstic uniform selection algorithm as described in he docs: https://se.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html

> The ga default selection function, Stochastic uniform, lays out a line in which each parent corresponds to a section of the line of length proportional to its scaled value. The algorithm moves along the line in steps of equal size. At each step, the algorithm allocates a parent from the section it lands on. The first step is a uniform random number less than the step size.

For myself the above docs can be interpreted in two ways:

1. Either a random number x will be picked initially and all subsequent "steps" are simply multiple of it.

   ```
   Step size: 1 
   Random x e.g. 0.5 
   Location on line: 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5
   ```
2. The algorithm moves along the line in fixed steps and additionally a random x < the fixed size is added every time.

   ```
   Fixed Step size: 1 
   Random x varies all the time but < 1
   Location on line: 1.1, 2.3, 3.2, 4.5, 5.1
   ```

Number 1 faces the issue that if the random value chosen is too small only the most fit individual will be selected as we don't move along the line at all. So is the 2nd interpretation correct?

As far as I understood the scaled fitness values sum up to the count of parents that will be generated, therefore isn't the *step size* always 1 since we can fit exactly as many steps * parents needed on the line?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a third interpretation for your consideration. The algorithm moves along the line in fixed steps. However, the starting point is less than the step size.

```
Fixed step size: 1
Randomly chosen start: 0.32
Locations on line: 0.32 1.32 2.32 3.32 4.32 5.32
```

By using a fixed step size, the algorithm knows exactly how many parents will be selected. For example, if the line is 100 units long, and the step size is 1, then exactly 100 parents will be selected. But which parents are selected is determined by the random starting point.

This assumes that there are multiple parents to choose from in each interval of length 1. And the most fit individual has a scaled length less than 1.